# Twitter Like text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

I am trying to walk through a table and get a specific TD with a name of note and cut it off at 40 characters and display "..." if the text is over 40 characters.

I wrote:

```
var element = $('.maintenanceTable').find('td[name="note"]');
console.log(element.text().length);
if(element.text().length > 40){
    element.text().substring(0, 10) + '....';
}
console.log(element)
```

The first `console.log` shows 115 characters, the second, shows a object returned .... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery functions like "text" generally have two forms. If you supply no arguments to them (e.g. `text()`), they give you the value contained in the element. But if you pass an argument (e.g. `text("something")`), then it sets the value.

So you want something like this:

```
var element = $('.maintenanceTable').find('td[name="note"]').first();
if(element.text().length > 40) {
  element.text(
    element.text().substring(0, 39) + '...'
  );
}
```